# SED Delete lines and replace with new from file

Tags: sed

Have been looking at SED documention but need a little pointer in the right direction

I have 200 files I want to modify in a batch.
Source is html file.
Need to create a new file for the changes.

Want to delete the first part of each file up to the first  tag (This is 20 or so lines but can vary slightly).
Then insert the contents of a source file (the same for all files) into the new target file starting at line 1, for 30 or so lines. The number of lines to insert does not match the number that are deleted though.

Hope you can help.

Paul

Answer (score 2):

This can certainly be done with sed(1), but I would probably use the vanilla editor ed(1).

```
$ cat > bigfix.sh
for i in "$@"; do
  ed "$i" << \eof
1,/<tag>/-1d
0r otherfile.html
w
q
eof
done
$ sh bigfix.sh file*.html
```

This shell script takes arguments and runs ed(1) on each arg. It deletes lines starting from the first and ending on the line right before the one with `<tag>`. It then puts `otherfile.html` at the top and writes out the result.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am not familiar with ed, and having checked not available on my server.  Is the syntax compatible with sed or something similar I could use?  Also is it possible to systematically sequqence through all files in a directory requiring modifciation rather than each one individually?  Great prompt response much appreciated. Paul

Comment: What OS is your server running?  I have to think it has /bin/ed or /usr/bin/ex. (Either will work.)  I'm confused about your sequence question. This script *does* systematically sequence through all files in a directory. You run **sh bigfix.sh \*.html** or something like it.

Comment: OK I will try later.  Sorry didn't grasp re sequencing - You have answered the question!

Answer (score 0):

For an individual file:

```
sed -e '1,/tag/{/tag/r insertfile' -e ';d}' inputfile > outputfile
```

For many files:

```
find . -name 'criterion*.ext' -type f -exec sh -c 'sed -e "1,/tag/{/tag/r insertfile" -e ';d}" "{}" > "{}.new"' \;
```

**Edit:**

Fixed the `find` command to use `sh` because of the redirection. Note the change in quoting from the previous version.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go in the morning.  Paul

Comment: Almost go this to do what I want. The problme I have is that I want the tag to be an html tag </tr>, when I try this I get an error - do I need to be escaping it in some way?  If I use a string it works fine.  Just needing to understand the syntax needed.

Comment: @Paul: It would help if you posted the error (I wonder why so many people say they get error messages but don't post them), but I suspect that it's "can't find label" or similar. The reason for that is the string "</tr>" includes a slash which is being used as the delimiter for the regex in `sed`. The solution is to use a different delimiter: `\|</tr>|`

Comment: Yes sorry was intending to but got sidetracked with the detail

sed: -e expression #2, char 3: unexpected `}'

was the error
So does your solution go within the the forward slashes from the previous example?
/\|</tr>|/
Forgive the basic as I'm a novice here

Comment: @Paul: No the `\|` takes the place of the first forward slash and the second `|` takes the place of the second slash. Instead of pipe characters, you could use any character as long as the first instance of it is escaped (of course, if you're using slashes, you don't need the escape).

Comment: @Dennis  Thanks the mods work fine with the individual file example.  I then moved onto applying the many file option.  I was expecting that a new file would be created for each file matching the criterion but what I currently get is one file {}.new with each version of the matching criterion file code (correctly modified with inserted code) appended together in the same file.  Code is shown here  find . -name '*.htm' -type f -exec sed -e '1,\|</tr>|{\|</tr>|r rht1.txt' -e ';d}' "{}" > "{}.new" \;
I'm not understanding how to replicate the target filename as the resultant filename.
Thanks Paul

Comment: If you've got GNU sed, or a BSD-ish sed, you can edit files in situ with 'sed' using the '-i' file.

Comment: @Jonathan: That's true and thanks for the comment, but the question mentioned that new files are wanted.

Comment: @Dennis: My entry: find . -name '*.htm' -type f -exec sh -c 'sed -e "1,\|</tr>|{\|</tr>|r rht1.txt" -e ';d}" "{}" > "{}.new"' \;
This just sits there with a ">" prompt rather than the "-bash-3.00$" prompt and no changes are made.

Comment: @Paul: You missed a single quote before the `;d`.

Comment: @Dennis:  I'm sure that the single quote is there in my example.   I copied and pasted from your updated example.  I did again to make sure and the result is the same as I quoted in the last reply   find . -name '*.htm' -type f -exec sh -c 'sed -e "1,\|</tr>|{\|</tr>|r rht1.txt" -e ';d}" "{}" > "{}.new"' \;  So I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: @Paul: Try this: `find . -name '*.htm' -type f -exec sh -c 'sed -e "1,\|</tr>|{\|</tr>|r rht1.txt" -e ";d}" "{}" > "{}.new"' \;`

Comment: @Dennis: That's it!  That seems to work perfectly now.  I will do a few more tests in the next couple of hours.  Many thanks for your patience.